# Showing ${(np+1)^{1/p}}{(nq+1)^{-1/q}}$ is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that sequence $\bigg (\frac{(np+1)^{1/p}}{(nq+1)^{1/q}}\bigg)_n$ is unbounded for $p<q$.

---

I tried more analytic approach by noticing that corresponding function has strictly positive derivative. But I'm not satisfied with it.
Can you help me find some lower estimation which is unbounded?

Comment: $\arctan(x)$ has strictly positive positive derivative yet is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a sequence is unbounded iff some power of it is unbounded. Raise everything to the power of $pq$, and our sequence is unbounded iff $$\left(\frac{(np+1)^q}{(nq+1)^p}\right)_n$$ is unbounded.

But the numerator there is bounded below by $n^qp^q$, and the denominator is bounded above by $pn^pq^p$ (for $n > 1/q$). Thus, the whole sequence is bounded below by $$\frac{n^qp^q}{pn^pq^p} = n^{q-p}(p^{q-1}q^{-p}).$$ 
The bit in the brackets there is constant, and since $q - p > 0$, we have $\left(n^{q-p}(p^{q-1}p^{-p}\right)_n\to\infty$, hence $$\left(\frac{(np+1)^q}{(nq+1)^p}\right)_n\to\infty,$$ and so $$\left(\frac{(np+1)^\frac{1}{p}}{(nq+1)^\frac{1}{q}}\right)_n\to\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n(p,q):=\frac{(np+1)^{1/p}}{(nq+1)^{1/q}}$ and show that , with $h:=q-p$, we have

$f_n(p,q)^{pq}=(\frac{np+1}{nq+1})^p (np+1)^h$. Since $\frac{np+1}{nq+1} \to l:=p/q$ as $n \to \infty$, we see that there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that

$\frac{np+1}{nq+1}  \ge l/2$ for $n > N$. Therefore

$ f_n(p,q) \ge (l/2)^{1/q}(np+1)^{\frac{h}{pq}}$ for $n>N$. Since $\frac{h}{pq}>0$, we get

$f_n(p,q) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

A positive derivative is not enough.  You could have a function like $1-\frac 1n$ that has positive derivative but is still bounded.

In this case, for an intuitive approach, when $n$ is very large the $+1$s will not matter so let's ignore them.  Then your function becomes $$\frac{(np)^{1/p}}{(nq)^{1/q}}=\frac {p^{1/p}}{q^{1/q}}n^{(1/p-1/q)}$$ which is clearly unbounded.  The leading part is some fixed constant and we know $1/p \gt 1/q$

To make this work we need to justify ignoring the $+1$ in the denominator.  Pick some $q'$ such that $p \lt q' \lt q$ and argue there is an $n$ large enough that $nq' \gt nq+1$, then you have $(nq')^{1/q'} \gt (nq+1)^{1/q}$